# Search for text in all files in Atlassian Stash

Tags: api

Supposed I have a git repo managed by Atlassian Stash. Can I search all files in all project for a specific text? is there such a tool out there, already?

If not, do you think it would be build-able using the API for Stash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code search is now a built-in feature of Bitbucket Server (formerly called Stash).  This was added in 2016.  See https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/03/24/introducing-code-search-for-bitbucket-server/.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such functionality in Stash itself (as discussed in the Atlassian bugtracker at STASH-2851), but there is a third-party plugin in the marketplace and on GitHub: https://github.com/palantir/stash-codesearch-plugin

It does, however, require an ElasticSearch node running alongside and doesn't seem to be trivially installable.

Answer (score 0):

There's a paid easier version to install on the marketplace currently:

https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.mohamicorp.stash.search-for-stash/server/overview

Comment: Could you possibly expand your answer to include some basic instructions on how to use this software?